# What's the need of NULL terminator at end of decrypted string?

Tags: c++, encryption, google-chrome-extension, openssl, google-nativeclient

I am working on a google chrome NaCl extension that involves encryption and decryption of data using openssl library functions. The encryption works perfectly and the decryption also works fine as of now but for that I had to put in a kind of hack but I am not sure if that's the correct way to handle it.

```
else if(action == "decryption")
    {
      pp::Var content = dict_message.Get("content");

      //aes decryption starts here
      pp::VarArrayBuffer buffer(content);
      const char *password = "password";
      unsigned char key[EVP_MAX_KEY_LENGTH], iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
      int cipherlen = buffer.ByteLength();
      int len = cipherlen + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH;
      unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char*)malloc(len*sizeof(unsigned char));
      unsigned char* ciphertext = static_cast<unsigned char*>(buffer.Map());

      aes_init(password, (int)strlen(password), key, iv);
      len = decrypt(ciphertext, cipherlen, key, iv, plaintext);
      buffer.Unmap();
      plaintext[len]='\0';  //fix a bug of overshooting plaintext sent
      //aes decryption ends here

      pp::VarDictionary reply;
      reply.Set("action","decryption");
      reply.Set("plaintext", (char*)plaintext);
      reply.Set("fileSize", len);
      PostMessage(reply);
      free(plaintext);
    }
```

Now this code decrypts the data and sends back to the javascript on extension page. Notice the line `plaintext[len]='\0';`, if I dont put it then sometimes I get a garbage after the correctly decrypted text in `plaintext` and that reflects as a `null` in my javascript. So is the correct way to handle the bug ?

Comment: The end of any c-style string needs to have a null terminator.  If you decryption method does not put it at the end of the string then you need to do it manually.

Comment: if the original data encryption did *not* include the terminating nullchar, neither will the decrypted data. Thus you have to provide one. My guess is somewhere the encryption code encrypted the string using something similar to `strlen()` and not `strlen()+1` for the original plaintext length. And btw, you should be using an RAII container like `std::vector<char> plaintext(len);` rather than manually jumping through the `malloc/free` ring of potential fire. Any exception thrown between that `malloc` and `free` is currently guaranteed to leak memory.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you're using a C-string, which must be NULL-terminated. When you call pp::VarDictionary::Set, [the parameters are pp::Vars](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ppapi/cpp/var_dictionary.h&l=70), and you're taking advantage of an [implicit conversion constructor from C-string to pp::Var.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ppapi/cpp/var.h&rcl=1427269032&l=49)

If instead you make plaintext a `std::string` or use `pp::VarArrayBuffer`, this won't be necessary. `PostMessage()` is optimized to deal with large `VarArrayBuffers`, so you should probably prefer that anyway. So I'd suggest replacing this line:

```
unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char*)malloc(len*sizeof(unsigned char));
```

with something like:

```
pp::VarArrayBuffer plaintext(len);
```

...and change your decrypt line to something like:

```
len = decrypt(ciphertext, cipherlen, key, iv,\b
              static_cast<unsigned char*>(plaintext.Map()));
```

Note, this will change the type JavaScript receives from a string to an ArrayBuffer. If you want it to remain a string, you can use a std::string instead:

```
std::string plaintext(len, '\0');
```

and access the string's buffer using operator[]. So the call to decrypt looks like this (I'm assuming len is >0):

```
len = decrypt(ciphertext, cipherlen, key, iv, &plaintext[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `'\0'` is the terminator for all strings in C. Since your output is in a string, if the `'\0'` character is missing, your program won't know where the string ends, and so may move on to areas beyond the string when using it, which corresponds to the garbage value near the end.

Whenever strings are declared, `'\0'` is put at the end. However, you are first allocating the memory for the decrypted text, and then writing into it. In this case you have to take care to at the string terminating character at the end.

The reason for the existence of the string terminating character is that strings are stored in the form of a character array in C, and the size of the array is not known by just the pointer to the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

If the `\0` is not there at the end of a c-string, the code will not know when the string ends and will walk off into unknown parts of memory. The null terminator lets the program know "this is the end of my string". Without this, you are inviting undefined behavior into your program.